# ngDialog change options while dialog is open

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

Is it possible to change options of an open dialog?

Specifically, I want to set `showClose`, `closeByEscape` and `closeByDocument` to `false`.

The reason is that I have a form in the dialog. On clicking *Save*, I make a request to the server. At the same time, I disable the buttons and also want to make sure that the dialog can’t be closed until there is a response. But I want the user to be able to easily close the dialog before they click *Save*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether you can do this explicitly by simply changing the values of those attributes, as they don't appear to be bound both ways. But there is a `preCloseCallback` attribute that you can set to prevent closing based on some local variable. So what I would do is, before the request, set some variable indicating the request is in progress. When the request finishes, reset that variable. Then, in the `preCloseCallback`, check whether that variable is set. Here is a simple example:

```
  $scope.toggleCloseable = function() {
    $scope.closeable = !$scope.closeable;
  }

  $scope.openDialog = function() {
    ngDialog.open({ 
      template: 'firstDialogId', 
      className: 'ngdialog-theme-default', 
      showClose: true,
      scope: $scope,
      preCloseCallback: function() {
        return $scope.closeable;
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is a simple plunker where that variable is set by a button press in the modal, but this could just as easily be set before & after a request is made. You'll see that when the `closeable` flag is false, none of the close actions work, but when it is true, it works as usual.

https://plnkr.co/edit/d4m0tryFdm8vWWgh7a4j

Comment: Nice one! I’ll give this a go.